# Custom nginx rbenv passenger rake not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

Someone is getting this kind of problem when try to compile passenger with a custom nginx install?

have any passenger version that compile without problem?

or is because of the rbenv?

thank's

```
 + ngx_pagespeed was configured
adding module in /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.19/src/nginx_module
*** The Phusion Passenger support files are not yet compiled. Compiling them for you... ***
*** Running 'rake nginx CACHING=false' in /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.19/src/nginx_module... ***
./configure: 28: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.19/src/nginx_module/config: rake: not found
make[1]: *** [config.arch.full] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/build/nginx-1.9.10'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Comment: what command you are running to install for compiling Nginx and passenger ?

Comment: @Muaaz Rafi i'm using sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b